# How do I allow family commenters to upload photos?

Tags: uploads

I'm trying my first WP site - a family blog. I'm hosting it on GoDaddy with a few other websites I work on.  Less than 20 people have access/permission to the family site. We're collecting old family photos and genealogy information (text). I'd like each person to be able to upload the photos they have found and use a comment area to describe the photo. I will gladly switch to WP.com if it would make it easier.  I just want this functionality.  How should I proceed?

TIA your help.

Comment: Hi JLucchesi, could you provide more details on what you've tried already (and why it didn't work)?

Comment: kraftner- Thanks for the response. What I've done is not all that technical.  When I started I thought this "photo w comment" function was a default feature in WP that I just had to switch on.  But I poked around the entire interface, created multiple trial member accounts and tried many (if not all) combinations of preferences with no luck.  I've been searching thru themes looking for this feature and not finding it. So, I gather from your reply that this is not a simple, common functionality.  Am I right?